# launch app in iPhone simulator failed after a time

Tags: visual-studio-2015, build, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

Hello I use Xamarin with Visualstudio Community 2015 on Windows 10
as build host I use Mac OSX 10.11.5 (El Capitan) with iPhone5 iOS 10.1 Simulator
I can build/launch/debug my app without problems for about 30 minutes, after that visualstudio
build the app than on launching the app in simulator the output window shows:

```
Launching 'myapp.iOS' on 'iPhone 5 iOS 10.1'...
Launch failed. The app 'myapp.iOS' could not be launched on 'iPhone 5 iOS  10.1'. Error: The post for client vs10440Matze on topic xvs/idb/4.2.1.64/launch-app has been cancelled. Please check the logs for more details.
The app has been terminated.
```

in the Ide.log at the windows machine I can see:

```
Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessagingClient Warning: 0 : [2016-12-09   10:48:38.4481] The post for client vs10440Matze on topic xvs/idb/4.2.1.64 /launch-app has been cancelled
System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
 at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
 at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
 at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessagingClient.<PostAsync>d__23`2.MoveNext()
```

at the mac-buildhost I can see:

IDB.log:

```
/Users/matze/Library/Caches/Xamarin/XMA/Agents/IDB/4.2.1.64/mlaunch --launchsim "/Users/matze/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/myapp.iOS/85cb5165734f657bdd8719a918480bd0/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/myapp.iOS.app" --device=:v2:udid=7E78B8AC-ACAB-4A11-AC9B-443766774A58 -argument=-monodevelop-port -argument=56852 --sdkroot "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer" -sdk 10.1
Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.MTouch Information: 0 : [2016-12-09 00:31:41.4471] MTouch Run Terminated
Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessagingClient Error: 0 : [2016-12-09 00:31:41.5180] An error occured on client IDB42164 while executing a reply for topic xvs/idb/4.2.1.64/launch-app
Xamarin.Messaging.Exceptions.MonotouchException: An error occurred while executing MTouch
at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.MTouch+<RunAsync>d__8.MoveNext () [0x0024a] in <003fb8ef983c4ea5910c8a47fc9dde09>:0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-mono-4.6.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-mono-4.6.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-mono-4.6.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-mono-4.6.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-mono-4.6.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:535
at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.MTouch+<RunAsync>d__7.MoveNext () [0x0007b] in <003fb8ef983c4ea5910c8a47fc9dde09>:0
```

also while building I can see in Build.log often repeating the message:

```
Xamarin.Messaging.Client.ApplicationMessageExtensions Warning: 0 : [2016-12-09 02:09:28.1124] Payload Type Xamarin.Messaging.Build.Contracts.ExecuteTaskMessage is incompatible with the requested content type Xamarin.Messaging.Build.Contracts.CopyItemMessage
Xamarin.Messaging.Client.ApplicationMessageExtensions Warning: 0 : [2016-12-09 02:09:28.5254] Payload Type Xamarin.Messaging.Build.Contracts.CopyItemMessage is incompatible with the requested content type Xamarin.Messaging.Build.Contracts.GetItemMessage
Xamarin.Messaging.Client.ApplicationMessageExtensions Warning: 0 : [2016-12-09 02:09:27.6058] Payload Type Xamarin.Messaging.Build.Contracts.CompareItemsMessage is incompatible with the requested content type Xamarin.Messaging.Build.Contracts.GetItemMessage
```

Visualstudio stops the debugging view than immediately. Restarting Visualstudio helps until it happens again.

About any help I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Try to close and reopen Visual Studio. This should resolve your issue :)

Comment: I already wrote "Restarting Visualstudio helps until it happens again." but thats not the kind of solution I am looking for..

Comment: I got this issue two times only. I think that the issue is with the Mac Agent that Xamarin execute on the iMac. Restarting VS, restart a new instance of the agent also.